# Size of canvas with video in it and the quality of video streamed

Tags: video-streaming, video-processing

I am playing around with the following example, to draw video and overlay to a canvas, and live stream it on YouTube.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/mmcc-next-streamr?path=pages%2Findex.js%3A1%3A0 (You can click on 'Show' to see it)

I have some requirements I'd like to satisfy for the Canvas and for the video sent to YouTube:

The canvas should:

1. have a responsive size
2. keep the aspect ratio when resized

The quality of the video sent to YouTube Live Streaming API should:

1. be unaffected by canvas size
2. be able to be controlled from my code

I was wondering if this is possible.

Isn't

```
const videoOutputStream = canvasRef.current.captureStream(30); // 30 FPS
```

in the code basically capturing what's on the canvas and sending that?

That means if the canvas is small, the video resolution will be compromised, right?

Is there a better way to do this? I really need to draw the overlay (there's no point for the app without the overlay), and I want to be flexible with the canvas size (e.g. small on mobile).

Another question is, the dimensions of the canvas are set statically like this:

```
canvasRef.current.height = videoRef.current.clientHeight;
canvasRef.current.width = videoRef.current.clientWidth;
```

Is this intended? Is it not recommended to make the canvas size adjustable in this case, since the video output can be affected while it's being resized?

I was trying wrapping the canvas in a resizable container and resizing the canvas based on the canvas size in `requestAnimationFrame` if the container size changes, but not sure if this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built an app similar to what you are describing: https://record.a.video (it streams to api.video, but can be used for any RTMP endpoint service)

Set the canvas size to the dimensions you want to stream.  That's what will be sent out of the browser.

Then use CSS to resize the canvas for the browser - making it responsive. For example - in this app, I have it set to 70% of the screen for desktop, and 66% of the screen for smaller devices.  It does not affect the size streamed.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. Can you point me to where exactly you are doing this? I've checked https://github.com/dougsillars/recordavideo/blob/main/public/style.css and https://github.com/dougsillars/recordavideo/blob/main/public/index.js but it's hard to locate where that's happening.

Comment: line 273 has the canvas at 70%. for small screens. Line 19 is for screens over 1200px and is 66%.